# Deleting records from 'orbeon_form_data_attach' due to ever growing size of the table

Tags: orbeon

We have Orbeon Form 4.6 PE running in our production environment for last 6 years. We have about 200 Forms and our `orbeon_form_data_attach` grew upto 15 GB at this point. We have been thinking about ways to to archive records from this table, and delete the records which have been created earlier than 6 months.

Here is the query that we tried in the copy of our production database, that brings down this table size from 15 GB to 6 GB.

```
DELETE orbeon_form_data, orbeon_form_data_attach
FROM
    (
        SELECT document_id
        FROM   orbeon_form_data
        WHERE  app <> 'orbeon' AND
               form <> 'builder' AND
               last_modified_time <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
    ) as deletions
INNER JOIN orbeon_form_data
ON         deletions.document_id=orbeon_form_data.document_id
LEFT JOIN  orbeon_form_data_attach
ON         orbeon_form_data.document_id = orbeon_form_data_attach.document_id ;
```

Our applications that are integrated with Orbeon Forms and consumes data from Orbeon database does not requires forms data submitted 6 month ago.

Would really like to know any possible side effect in Orbeon application itself, if we go ahead with this query in our Production.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems with this:

1. Most importantly, in some cases this will remove too much data, as `orbeon_form_data` works a little bit like a journal, where new rows are added, but "never" updated or deleted. Say, a new form instance (document id) was created 1 year ago, and was just updated today: you'll then have 2 rows with the same `document_id` but different `last_modified_time`, and your query will delete this document because one of the 2 has a `last_modified_time` older than 6 months.
2. The above query could be updated to avoid the problem mentioned in point 1, but it might be more aggressive than need be.

So, I would recommend:

1. You start with the queries in the [Purging Old Data](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/purging-old-data.html) section of the documentation, which are a bit more conservative. The first there removes *deleted* data older than *x* months, and the second removes attachments that are not referenced anymore. Start with those, and see if this brings down the amount of data to something that is more reasonable for you.
2. If that doesn't remove enough data, in your above query, try replacing the subquery inside `( … ) as deletions` by the query below. And be very, very, *very*, careful when running this: re-read the query to make sure it makes sense, and do a backup of your data before running it on any sensitive data.

   ```
   SELECT document_id
   FROM   orbeon_form_data d,
          (
            SELECT   document_id, max(last_modified_time) last_modified_time
            FROM     orbeon_form_data
            WHERE    app  <> 'orbeon' AND
                     form <> 'builder'
            GROUP BY document_id
          ) l
   WHERE  d.document_id          = l.document_id        AND
          d.last_modified_time   <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
   ```

Also, I should mention that sometimes one's motivation for removing data isn't to save disk space, but to improve performance. In this respect, [Orbeon Forms 2016.2](http://blog.orbeon.com/2016/08/orbeon-forms-20162.html) has new indices that greatly improve the performance of the summary page and the search API when you have a lot of data.

Comment: Hi Alex, 

Thanks for the detail feedback. Our primary concern is application database size. 

Total database size : 25 GB
Orbeon form attachment table : 15 GB

We have tried removing only deleted data in past, without any significant gain in terms of database size.
Based on our application design, we parse and persist the subnitted Orbeon form data along with attachment, that lead us to come up with 
the deletion of all Orbeon data and attachments, whcih are 6 month or older.

We will run queries you mentioned in our copy of production database, and post the results.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Bilal, got it, you'll let me know if the 2 "conservative" queries remove enough data for you. If not, we'll come up with an updated version of the query you had that doesn't have the problem mentioned in my "point 1" above.

Comment: Hi Alex, 

Here are the results of conservative queries on production database.

Query 1: Returns 0 rows . 
Reason:  This query delete records which are deleted through Orbeon UI (Form Builder or Form Runner), but we don't have any use case that does it. 


Query 2: Returns 7 rows .

Comment: Hi Bilal, so, in other words, in your case, this doesn't help :). So I can try the query on an actual database, what relational database are you using? (I tried your query on Oracle, but this doesn't seem to be it.)

Comment: Hi Alex, We are usign MySQL version 5.6.

Comment: Hi Bilal, understood, I update your above query, test it on MySQL, and post a follow-up here.

Comment: Hi Alex, 

I don't see the updated query, you mean you will post it after testing it in MySQL ? 

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Bilal, I apologize for the delay; this fell through the cracks! So, I updated my answer above with the subquery you can use. You'll let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks Alex. We will execute the query and post the results here.